# Multiple ASP.NET web applications with common Login(authentication)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I have created created 2 separate Asp.Net Application. 
App 1: Admin
App 2: Reports

We already hosted **Admin** Application in IIS 7.0.
Now I need to provide a link in **Admin** Application to link to **Reports** App, where in which i should not login again to Reports app.

Now I have created virtual directory for **Reports** in IIS under **Admin** App.
So my question is how to provide a common Authentication for both Applications.??
**Note**: I am Using Forms Authentication

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to do three things in the configuration, and each application must match:

- Have the same `Application` attribute in the membership and role providers and use the same database: `applicationName` attribute on `add` child of `provider` child of [`membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/whae3t94.aspx) and [`roleManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms164662.aspx). This means authentication and authorisation data will be shared.
- Have the same keys to encrypt and validate authentication cookies (on the [`machineKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) element). (This also means logins will survive app pool restarts because new keys won't be generated on each app start.)
- Have both apps use the same `name` attribute on the [`forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) element so the same cookie is used.

[Updated with third point after finding the rigth attribute.]

Comment: @Jupaol: No. I have used points 1 & 2, but not the third part. AlsoL anyone just using some information from the web without testing gets what they deserve.

Answer (score 2):

You may want an application instead of virtual directory under the admin app.

You will need to set enableCrossAppRedirects="true" in the web.config

Both apps should share a common machineKey. Here's a tool to generate a machineKey:
http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Sample web.config entries:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPNETAUTH"
      enableCrossAppRedirects="true"
      loginUrl="Login.aspx"
      protection="All"
      path="/"
      timeout="60" />
</authentication>


<machineKey validationKey='F1D92DF9B41E5D94E79946A10494F52FF26956F256667DB52E9FA9B30E6A4FF61E4C05F1AC2795330F34B7B1389E1BD75FD0D3DCD12E991BD09B9AD004C0FE0D'
            decryptionKey='B8940FB4A776EABD1525E7D9B58E9E5DE057B2F2A67AA913'
            validation='SHA1'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoul take a look at [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx) and [Managed Extensibility Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you need to use the same machine key, validation key and decryption key in each of the web.config files.

Also, make sure all of your forms auth parameters match in each file.

The reports app should direct to the Admin app's login page.